# How to remove the content of a string between quotes with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
var content = '<a href="www.topSecret.com">Link</a>'
```

My goal main is:

```
var content = '<span>Link</span>'
```

OR if not possible at least:

```
var content = '<a href="" >Link</a>'
```

Some notes:

1. this var will be sent to a PHP variable so if it's easier to do with PHP its also accepted
2. jQuery most welcome

Thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var input = '<a href="www.topSecret.com">Link</a>';  
  pattern = /<a.+>(.*?)<\/a>/;
  matches = input.match(pattern);
  result = '<span>' + matches[1] + '</span>';
  alert(result);
```

Here is working sample: http://jsbin.com/oqikib/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

Easily done in PHP with [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags):

```
$str = '<a href="www.topSecret.com">Link</a>';
$result = '<span>' . strip_tags( $str) . '</span>';
echo $result;
```

**Output:**

```
<span>Link</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just wondering, what if the content has a full html content with tables and tr's and td's and I need to find only the 'a' tag?

Comment: @user - You'd use an HTML parser, but you didn't specify anything like that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

### jQuery Version

```
var $content = $('<a href="www.topSecret.com">Link</a>');
var result = "<span>" + $content.text() + "</span>";
```